# FTP Shell - Get all files that do not equal a condition

Tags: vba, shell, ftp

I'm currently using VBA (Excel) to call the FTP Shell to grab files from a directory.  I want to grab all files in the directory that do not contain the wildcard %payment%, but I'm not sure of the syntax.

```
Sub executeFTPBatch()
    Call Shell("FTP -i -s:C:\temp\ftp_directions.txt")
End Sub
```

So my text file opens the FTP server, inputs the user/pw and then selects the directory.  I just need the command to put into the text file. Something like

```
mget *. * where filename != %payment% "c:\temp\" "ftp://currentfolder"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what is "wildcard %payment%".

Though the built-in Windows `ftp.exe` does *not* support negative masks in any way.

---

I can suggest these solutions:

- Run the `ftp.exe` once to get a directory listing (the `ls` command); parse the listing in your VBA code; select the files you want; and dynamically generate another `ftp` script to download these files.
- Use another command-line FTP client, that supports negative masks.

  For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) you can do:

  ```
  Call Shell( _
      "C:\path\WinSCP.com /log=C:\path\excel.log /command " & _
      """open ftp://user:password@example.com/"" " & _
      """get /path/* C:\path\ -filemask=|*%payment%*"" " & _
      """exit""")
  ```

  To ease reading, the above runs these WinSCP commands:

  ```
  open ftp://user:password@example.com/
  get /path/* C:\path\ -filemask=|*%payment%*
  exit
  ```

  If you prefer, you can put the commands to a script file and run the script with the [`/script=` command-line parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting), similarly to the `ftp -s:`, instead of the `/command`.

  See the guide to [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

  See also [WinSCP file mask reference](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

  Alternatively you can use [WinSCP .NET assembly via COM](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_vb) from the VBA code.

  *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thank you!, this is a great idea.